Book series where the girl becomes the queen and the boy a wizard; they marry and one of their children turns evil and dies
There was a book series I used to read as a teenager, about 15 years ago, where the girl (queen) and the boy (wizard) later get married and have children. One of the daughters(?) chooses the dark side and the father (wizard) dies. The series end with the queen having a feast of some sort and there were some old witches smiling, while seeing the ghost of the wizard standing behind the queen, smiling.
